# Read File from PATH in Cobol as UTF-8

Tags: xml, unix, utf-8, cobol, mainframe

In an experimental feature exploration, I found some astounding behaviour when I try to load a Unix file that is UTF-8 on a mainframe system using Cobol and declaring the FD record as Unicode alphanumeric.

If my record length is 10 (ie. `10   chunk  PIC U(10)`, first 10 characters are correctly loaded. Then 30 (apparently 3x the length according to exploration) is skipped, then it reads again 10 characters. Then the next 10 characters are read into my next record.

Source Code of my program:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.   loadutf8.
       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT XMLFILE ASSIGN TO "XML".
       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD XMLFILE RECORDING MODE F.
          01  chunk PIC  U(10).
       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
          01  EOF   PIC  X.
       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       START-PROGRAM.
           OPEN INPUT XMLFILE.
           PERFORM WITH TEST after  UNTIL EOF = 'T'
              READ XMLFILE
              AT END MOVE 'T' TO EOF
              NOT AT END
               DISPLAY FUNCTION DISPLAY-of (chunk)
              END-READ
           END-PERFORM.
           CLOSE XMLFILE.
           GOBACK.
       END PROGRAM loadutf8.
```

JOB-CARD:

```
//COBOL     EXEC IGYWCLG,LNGPRFX=IGY630 
//SYSIN       DD DISP=SHR,DSN=COB.SRC(loadutf8) 
//GO.XML      DD PATH='/u/utf8.xml'
```

My UTF-8 file:

```
<?xml  ?>
<!-- 0 --><!-- 1 --><!-- 2 --><!-- 3 --><!-- 4 --><!-- 5 --><x>???</x>
```

Output observed:

```
<?xml  ?>   
<!-- 3 -->
```

To me, it looks like consistently reading the chunk according to size, *skip 3 times* and then goes to next chunk size, etc..

What could be causing this?

Is there a best practice to it, how to load a Unix file to a XML and use a variable that has the usage UTF-8? Preferably w/o any hacks, just using 'standard' language features.

Just asking this out of curiosity, any idea on how to explain the observed outcome is appreciated.

Comment: You use `RECORDING MODE IS F` which seems wrong for your case - does the behavior change when dropping it?

Comment: Thanks @SimonSobisch that mode `F` is the default (fixed), I also tried other modes that are allowed (V, U) but there was always the same output as a result.

Comment: Regarding the XML-parsing, there is a better suited way to parse the UTF-8, in contrast to load it to a Picture U(). Just read the size of chunks of Picture X() that you like and while parsing, the *End-of-Input event* will signal immediately when you should read another chunk of data from the file, set *XML-CODE to 1*, and continue parsing until End-of-Document.

Comment: Can you please post a complete answer about that with the code above being adjusted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native UTF-8 support seems to have been introduced with IBM Enterprise Cobol V6.3. I don't have experience with this, but from reading the manual, I can explain what happens. I *cannot*, however, say whether this is desired behaviour or a bug.

Anyway, in the Programmers Guide (v6.4), topic [Defining UTF-8 data items](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=cobol-defining-utf-8-data-items), one can read:

> **Fixed character-length UTF-8 data items.**
>
> This type of UTF-8 data item is defined when the PICTURE clause contains one or more 'U' characters, or a single 'U' character followed by a repetition factor, and neither the BYTE-LENGTH phrase of the PICTURE clause nor the DYNAMIC LENGTH clause is specified.

and further

> For fixed character-length UTF-8 data items, **the number of bytes reserved for the data item in memory is 4 × n**, where n is the number of characters specified in the definition of the item. Note that, due to the varying length nature of the UTF-8 encoding, even after moving n characters to a UTF-8 data item of length n, it is not necessarily the case that all 4 × n reserved bytes are needed to hold the data. It depends on the size of each character in the data.

In the chapter on [Processing QSAM files](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=program-processing-qsam-files), one can read

> You can also access byte-stream files in the z/OS UNIX file system using QSAM. These files are binary byte-oriented sequential files with no record structure. The record definitions that you code in your COBOL program and **the length of the variables that you read into and write from determine the amount of data transferred.**

I conclude from this that Cobol is simply advising the underlying I/O routine (QSAM) to read a many bytes as *reserved for the receiving variable*, which in your example is 40 bytes at a time. After all, QSAM does *not* support interpreting data as it is being read; it simply reads a given number of bytes, not characters, and places them in the input buffer.

The bytes will be interpreted as UTF-8 characters only when the variable is used later, such as in the DISPLAY statement. And, the length of the variable in number of UTF-8 characters as *defined* is then respected.

I did some quick test and read in some file which contains characters which need more than one byte in UTF-8 and the data displayed was shifted accordingly.

Not sure yet how to successfully process UTF-8 UNIX files with COBOL.

Comment: Thank you @phunsoft for your comprehensive answer. Yes, I fully agree, since all the characters are of 1 bit size, the observed offsets make perfect sense. Perhaps it might be a consideration using (or creating) a service/library to load the file into the variable, as then UTF-8 reading might be more feasible at that point.

Comment: @MJG you _may_ get away with reading the data as `PIC X` and have a redefine as `PIC U` and use it from there (would be of course create issues when there's a multibyte at then end). Otherwise moving the reading out to a library `CALL`ed sounds most reasonable.

Comment: @SimonSobisch the redefines helps for solving the current issue, thanks you. Yes, the multibyte at end situation would have to be handled correctly, and to code this out in COBOL seems to be feasible.

Comment: From the Language Reference: *When UTF-8 data contains combining character sequences, programmers are responsible for ensure that operations on UTF-8 characters do not unintentionally separate the multiple groupings of encoding units that form graphic characters. You must pay attention to the reference modification and avoid truncations during moves. The COBOL runtime system does not check for a split between the groups of encoding units that form a graphic character.* What a half-hearted UTF-8 support!

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM, there is a well documented example regarding XML-PARSE using segmented file input using `XMLPARSE(XMLSS)` compiler option, and the recent XML-PARSE in Z/OS should correctly handle the encoding used from a picture X of dynamic lenght:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.4?topic=examples-example-parsing-xml-document-one-segment-time
The event-handler should react to the XML-Event `END-OF-INPUT` accordingly:

```
 Handle-parse-events.                                                     
      Add 1 to Event-number                                                
      Display '  ' Event-number ': ' XML-event '{' XML-text '}'            
      Evaluate XML-event                                                   
        When 'END-OF-INPUT'                                                
          Read Input-XML                                                   
          Evaluate Input-XML-status                                        
            When 0                                                         
              Move 1 to XML-code                                           
              Display 'Continuing with: ' fdrec                            
            When 10                                                        
              Display 'At EOF; no more input.'                             
            When other                                                     
              Display 'Read failed, file status:' Input-XML-status         
              Goback                                                       
          End-evaluate                                                     
        When other                                                         
          Continue                                                         
      End-evaluate                                                         
           .
```